# How to address S3 error: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed? Java

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, parquet

I am trying to get and read a parquet file on S3 with the Apache Parquet Reader, and my code looks something like this:

```
ParquetReader<GenericData.Record> reader = null;
Path internalPath = new Path("s3://S3AccessID:S3SecretKey@bucketName/tmp0.parquet");
try {
            InputFile inputFile = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(internalPath, new Configuration());
            reader = AvroParquetReader.<GenericData.Record>builder(inputFile).build();
            GenericData.Record record;
            while ((record = reader.read()) != null) {
                System.out.println(record);
            }
}
```

However, when I build and run a program, this is the error screen:

```
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.get(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.retrieveINode(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:195)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.retrieveINode(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem.getFileStatus(S3FileSystem.java:332)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.fromPath(HadoopInputFile.java:39)
        at read.read.readParquetFile(read.java:153)
        at read.read.main(read.java:80)
Caused by: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/%2Ftmp0.parquet' XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message><RequestId>1A66095653EBAD50</RequestId><HostId>jNzbaMmKmszHiLvzA4NsqILRxF+qJFxJLTWvKVwqHoggB0MnYy1ESoajHaa/Ufs5RE8ghs31Jaw=</HostId>
```

> Does anyone have any idea how to address this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like your S3 bucket region uses Signature Version 4 (v4) signing protocol and does not support the older version (v2).

> The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please
>   use **AWS4-HMAC-SHA256**.

In that case, you must set the property `fs.s3a.endpoint` either in `core-site.xml` or in the Job configuration. The value for this property can be found here under [Amazon S3 Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_region).

Additionally,

1. Use hadoop's `s3a` client instead of `s3`.
2. Rather than embedding the access_key and secret_access_key in the s3a URL, use these properties `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key`. The entire list of properties that can be used for S3 authentication can be found [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authentication_properties).

Comment: I see, thanks! I added a core-site.xml file in the same folder as my main java file, and inputed the following properties and their respective values: <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>, <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>, and  <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>, but when I build and run the program, the same error still comes up. How do I know the values are passed in, and what should I write for the path?

Comment: The `core-site.xml` will be located inside the Hadoop installation directory under `etc/hadoop`, you have to add these properties to that file. If this is a multinode cluster, this change has to be made in all the nodes. Then restart the cluster (not sure if it is required for these properties, restart it to be sure). Path should be `s3a://bucket-name/tmp0.parquet`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I don't think I used the installed Hadoop--I downloaded gradle dependencies and used their library. Is there a way to configure the properties through there? I also just installed hadoop and changed the core-site.xml there. I'm not sure it does anything yet. Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: Okay I presume that you have built the Jar without having an active Hadoop platform to run. You can either setup a pseudo distributed Hadoop cluster to test your code or try for running it in local mode with the Hadoop libraries bundled in the Jar. In that case, set the properties within the job as part of configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I did this: Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   conf.set("fs.s3.endpoint", "s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com");
   conf.set("fs.s3.access.key", "accessKey"); 
   conf.set("fs.s3.secret.key", "secretKey");
I also tried with s3a, but still the same error occurs. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: It must be `s3a` instead of `s3`. And initialize a Job with this conf. Just curious, is your bucket in Oregon? Oregon should accept v2 signature! Is your path updated correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211657/discussion-between-nicholas-liu-and-franklinsijo).